# Where did my comments go?

Tags: support, comments

I'm pretty sure I made two comments on [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114579/htaccess-rewrite-whole-dir-contents-to-another) yesterday, one of which I deleted. However, today I have no comments on the question?

Just curious what happened to my comment?

---

**UPDATE 2018-05-20:** This just happened again. On [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115246/how-to-avoid-long-file-names-being-truncated-when-the-server-lists-the-folder-co). And the scenario was similar... I wrote one (short) comment on the question itself that I later deleted and then wrote another (longer) comment, which has since *vanished*? So, at the time of writing, there are no comments that remain. This time I was definitely on a wired/reliable connection.

Comment: There is only one deleted comment from you and you deleted it yourself: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVESx.png   It looks like other comments may never have made it into the system.

Comment: I did delete several other comments from myself and the original poster after they edited their question to address inconsistencies.

Comment: Does the [access to moderator tools privilege](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (which you have) not give you access to deleted comments?  I know it gives you access to deleted questions and answers.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "It looks like other comments may never have made it into the system." - Yeah, maybe that was it. I think I entered that comment on a WiFi connection (which does sometimes drop out) - but I thought I then saw the comment again later on a wired connection - maybe not?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "Does the access to moderator tools privilege ... not give you access to deleted comments?" - No, that seems to be a "moderator-only" thing.

Comment: It does seem to be moderator only.  I can't find any deleted comments on StackOverflow where I have that privilege but am not a moderator.